# Omit duplicate rows then pick the surviving row base on certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have the following data in my table

```
id   id2  flag
 1    11  0 <- this row should not be part of the result
 1    12  1 <- this row should survive the distinct operation
 2    13  0
 3    14  0
```

I want my result to be

```
id   id2  flag
 1    12  1
 2    13  0
 3    14  0
```

How would I construct a query like such?

Thanks

EDIT1: Sorry, using two column dummy data doesn't correctly reflect the problem I am facing.  I added another column, which complicates the problem.  As you can see I can't group on id2 because they are all unique.  But the row with id2 = 11 should be omitted from the result.

EDIT2: Changed the question to use 'omit' instead of 'remove'

EDIT3:

```
select id, id2, max(flag)
from table
group by id, id2
```

This query returns all 4 rows because group by id2 includes all 4 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with CTE as
(
select 
    row_number() over (partition by id order by flag desc) as rn, 
    id, 
    id2, 
    flag
    from myTable
)

SELECT * from CTE where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

When you want to apply additional criteria to the data, you typically use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`. For example, if you would like to keep `flag` of `1` if it exists, or keep zero otherwise, you can do this:

```
SELECT id, MAX(flag) as flag -- Since 1 > 0, MAX() works fine
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id                  -- This keeps only distinct ids
```

**EDIT :** (in response to edits #2&3)

Another solution would be using `NOT EXISTS` in a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT id, id2, flag
FROM myTable o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM myTable i WHERE o.id=i.id AND i.flag > o.flag
)
```

Comment: I chose mr.Reband answer because CTE is probably made for this type of query.